# belongsTo only being set on first and last member of hasMany

Tags: ember-data

My adapter uses `findHasMany` to load child records for a `hasMany` relationship. 
My `findHasMany` adapter method is directly based on the [test case for `findHasMany`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/has_many_test.js#L112). It retrieves the contents of the `hasMany` on demand, and eventually does the following two operations:

```
store.loadMany(type, hashes);
// ...
store.loadHasMany(record, relationship.key, ids);
```

(The full code for the `findHasMany` is below, in case the issue is there, but I don't think so.)

The really strange behavior is: it seems that somewhere within `loadHasMany` (or in some subsequent async process) **only the first and last child records get their inverse `belongsTo` property set**, even though all the child records are added to the `hasMany` side. I.e., if `posts/1` has 10 comments, this is what I get, after everything has loaded:

```js
var post = App.Posts.find('1');
post.get('comments').objectAt(0).get('post'); // <App.Post:ember123:1>
post.get('comments').objectAt(1).get('post'); // null
post.get('comments').objectAt(2).get('post'); // null
// ...
post.get('comments').objectAt(8).get('post'); // null
post.get('comments').objectAt(9).get('post'); // <App.Post:ember123:1>
```

My adapter is a subclass of `DS.RESTAdapter`, and I don't think I'm overloading anything in my adapter or serializer that would cause this behavior.

Has anybody seen something like this before? It's weird enough I though someone might know why it's happening.

## Extra

Using `findHasMany` lets me load the contents of the `hasMany` only when the property is accessed (valuable in my case because calculating the array of IDs would be expensive). So say I have the classic posts/comments example models, the server returns for posts/1:

```
{
  post: {
    id: 1,
    text: "Linkbait!"
    comments: "/posts/1/comments"
  }
}
```

Then my adapter can retrieve `/posts/1/comments` on demand, which looks like this:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      id: 201,
      text: "Nuh uh"
    },
    {
      id: 202,
      text: "Yeah huh"
    },
    {
      id: 203,
      text: "Nazi Germany"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code for the `findHasMany` method in my adapter:

```js
findHasMany: function(store, record, relationship, details) {
    var type = relationship.type;
    var root = this.rootForType(type);
    var url = (typeof(details) == 'string' || details instanceof String) ? details : this.buildURL(root);
    var query = relationship.options.query ? relationship.options.query(record) : {};

    this.ajax(url, "GET", {
        data: query,
        success: function(json) {
            var serializer = this.get('serializer');
            var pluralRoot = serializer.pluralize(root);
            var hashes = json[pluralRoot]; //FIXME: Should call some serializer method to get this?

            store.loadMany(type, hashes);

            // add ids to record...
            var ids = [];
            var len = hashes.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                ids.push(serializer.extractId(type, hashes[i]));
            }
            store.loadHasMany(record, relationship.key, ids);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the payload returned by `/posts/1/comments`?

Comment: @Cyril, added as requested. This is "air code", but I think the example is representative--i.e., there are no foreign key IDs in any of the child objects or anything that should affect the relationship linkage in the children. In the real data, technically there are those foreign keys, but the names don't match--so it can't be that Ember Data is figuring out that they're related that way. And at any rate, it's consistent between all the records, nothing different in the first and last ones.

Comment: You are not returning any `posts` in your payload. I'm tempted to believe that this is related to that issue https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Override the `DS.RelationshipChange.getByReference` method by inserting the following code into your app:

```js
DS.RelationshipChange.prototype.getByReference = function(reference) {
  var store = this.store;

  // return null or undefined if the original reference was null or undefined
  if (!reference) { return reference; }

  if (reference.record) {
    return reference.record;
  }

  return store.materializeRecord(reference);
};
```

Yes, this is overriding a private, internal method in Ember Data. Yes, it may break at any time with any update. I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Ember Data, but I'm not 100% certain this is the *right* solution. But it does solve this problem, and possibly other relationship-related problems.

This fix is designed to be applied to Ember Data master as of 29 Apr 2013.

## Reason

`DS.Store.loadHasMany` calls `DS.Model.hasManyDidChange`, which retrieves references for all the child records and then `set`s the hasMany's `content` to the array of references. This kicks off a chain of observers., eventually calling `DS.ManyArray.arrayContentDidChange`, in which the first line is `this._super.apply(this, arguments);`, calling the superclass method `Ember.Array.arrayContentDidChange`. **That `Ember.Array` method includes an optimization that caches the first and last object in the array and calls `objectAt` on only those two array members.** So there's the part that singles out the first and last record.

Next, since `DS.RecordArray` implements an `objectAtContent` method (from `Ember.ArrayProxy`), the `objectAtContent` implementation calls `DS.Store.recordForReference`, which in turn calls `DS.Store.materializeRecord`. **This last function adds a `record` property to the reference that is passed in as a side effect.**

Now we get to what I think is a bug. In `DS.ManyArray.arrayContentDidChange`, after calling the superclass method, it loops through all the new references and creates a `DS.RelationshipChangeAdd` instance that encapsulates the owner and child record references. But the first line inside the loop is:

```
var reference = get(this, 'content').objectAt(i);
```

Unlike what happens above to the first and last record, this calls `objectAt` directly on the `Ember.NativeArray` and bypasses the `ArrayProxy` methods including the `objectAtContent` hook, **which means that `DS.Store.materializeRecord`--which adds the `record` property on the reference object--may have never been called on some references.**

Next, the relationship changes created in the loop are immediately afterward (in the same run loop) applied with this call tree: `DS.RelationshipChangeAdd.sync` -> `DS.RelationshipChange.getFirstRecord` -> `DS.RelationshipChange.getByReference`. **This last method expects the reference object to have a `record` property.** However, the `record` property is only set on the first and last reference objects, for reasons explained above. Therefore, for all but the first and last records, the relationship fails to be established because it doesn't have access to the child record object!

The above fix calls `DS.Store.materializeRecord` whenever the `record` property doesn't exist on the reference. The last line in the function is the only thing added. On the one hand, it *looks* like this was the original intention: that `var store = this.store;` line in the original declares a variable that isn't otherwise used in the function, so what's it there for? Also, without the added line, the function doesn't always return a value, which is a little unusual for a function which is expected to do so. On the other hand, this could lead to mass materialization in some cases where that would be undesirable (but, the relationships just won't work without it in some cases, it seems).

### Possibly related

The "chain of observers" I mentioned takes a bit of an odd path. The initiating event was setting the `content` property on a `DS.ManyArray`, which extends `Ember.ArrayProxy`--therefore the `content` property has a dependent property `arrangedContent`. Importantly, the observers on `arrangedContent` are executed *before* observers on `content` are executed (see `Ember.propertyDidChange`). However, the default implementation of `Ember.ArrayProxy.arrangedContentArrayDidChange` simply calls `Ember.Array.arrayContentDidChange`, which `DS.ManyArray` implements! **The point being, this looks like a recipe for some code to execute in an unintended order.** That is, I think `Ember.ManyArray.arrayContentDidChange` may getting executed earlier than expected. If this is the case, the above mentioned code that expects the `record` property to already exist on all references may have been expecting this reasonably, as one of the observers directly on the `content` property may call `DS.Store.materializeRecord` on each reference. But I haven't dug deep enough to find out if this is true.

Comment: Built a failing test case that seems to confirm this issue, and the fix doesn't fail any tests. Submitted [pull request #953](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/953), maybe this will get into master.